# How many tons of diamonds did European colonies take from Africa?

Tags: europe, united-kingdom, africa, colony, imperialism

Last night I watched a movie & it said a London Diamond Company in 60s had more than 3 tons of diamonds.  Are those all from Africa? What is the total amount of diamonds that Europeans took from Africa in the colonial period?

Comment: As it stands, this is a bit too broad. If it was about a single colony of a single nation it would be better.

Comment: also, where is your evidence that that 3 tons, or even a significant part of it, was removed from Africa during the colonial period. The diamond mines operated by de Beers produce large quantities of diamonds every year.

Comment: This question can't be too broad because it asks for a single number - it can't be narrower. The fact that we don't know the answer and somebody could suppose it has never been researched and therefore answering it would require a big effort and cite a large amount of sources doesn't make it different from any other legitimate question whose answer we ignore.

Comment: @Pere The main question is asking for a single number, totalling **all** the diamonds taken by **all** the European colonial powers from **all** the European colonies in Africa.  That's pretty broad. The subsidiary question ("_Are those all from Africa_?"), is impossible to answer without at least knowing the name of the London diamond company the movie referred to.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - The number of all the diamonds taken by all the European colonial powers from all the European colonies in Africa might have been previously researched and be available in some source - or maybe it isn't. It may be a difficult question, but it isn't broad. If it were broad, questions like how many people where in **all** countries in **all** continents in the world in 1980 would be even broader, but widely researched and easily answerable because of that research - but just as legitimate as the total number of diamonds asked in the question.

Comment: @Pere Actually, that is a false comparison. A question about population would almost certainly be closed as [too basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_past_population_(United_Nations,_estimates)), since the data has been publicly tracked for decades.  In contrast, much (perhaps most) diamond extraction was carried out by private companies like [De Beers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Beers). Accurate totals are problematic even in countries where there is relatively good data, and the question has been the central theme of several books.